# How create DataTemplate depended from type of field in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, types, datatemplate

I know this. I can declare types:

```
public class TreeViewItemData : ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemData>
{
    public Object DataContext { get; set; } 
}
public class TreeViewItemData1 : ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemData>
{
    public Object DataContext { get; set; } // Store data of UserType1
}
public class TreeViewItemData2 : ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemData>
{
    public Object DataContext { get; set; } // Store data of UserType2
}
```

and declare HierarchicalDataTemplate:
- for UserType1:
    
       
           .....

- for UserType2:

     
         .....

But I want make dependence from type of field. Like this:
- for UserType1:
    
       
           .....

- for UserType2:

     
         .....

And not declare types: TreeViewItemData1 and TreeViewItemData2

Comment: you should be knowing the type on which you want to create heirarchy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implicit data template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DataTemplating_HeirarchicalDataTemplate) like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="om:Alarm">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="om:Information">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```